# Why doesn't the function printk() use a comma to separate parameters?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

An example `printk` call:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Log message.\n");
```

Perhaps this question is more about C in general, because I've never seen a function in C before that separated parameters without a comma.

How does this work? What does the compiler do with this information? Since the log level is an integer and the message is a pointer to a char array, it must pass them separately.

Comment: Compiler-supported string literal concatenation. Look at the definition of `KERN_INFO`. I don't do kernels, but I bet it is a string literal `#define`

Comment: @WhozCraig: String literal concatenation isn't merely compiler-supported. It's defined by the language, and has been since 1989.

Comment: Note that multiple arguments *are* separated by commas: `printfk(KERN_INFO "n = %d\n", n);`. The format string `KERN_INFO "n = %d\n"` is the first argument, and `n` is the second.

Comment: I don't want to edit my original question, so I'll put this here. Does anyone have insight as to why the linux kernel would parse messages like this? Why not pass these as separate arguments?

Comment: @KeithThompson Completely not what I meant, though if wordsmithed strict enough, you certainly could slice it that way. i meant, and still mean, the compiler concatenated the string literals. Had I intended to say it was dependent on some subset of compiler implementations, I can assure you I would have said "Compiler-*dependent*", which would obviously be wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I wasn't disagreeing with what you wrote, just expanding on it. "Compiler-supported" doesn't necessarily imply that *all* C compilers implement it.

Comment: `printk` is analogous to `printf`, which takes a format string and zero or more following arguments. And it's possible (this is sheer speculation) that early versions of Linux didn't support different log levels; adding them by prepending a string to the format wouldn't have broken existing code.

Comment: `Why not pass these as separate arguments?` efficiency.  Why would you want to `push` an extra arg separately, and then have printk pre-pend it to the string?  In ABIs that pass the first few args in registers, that effectively wastes an arg-passing register. There's also a code-size advantage.  The machine instruction to push an immediate integer is always going to be larger than prepending the data directly into the string. Passing a pointer instead of the actual bytes to be pre-pended is even worse, because then the bytes need to be stored somewhere AND you need a 32bit pointer in the code.

Comment: @PeterCordes That makes perfect sense. I always thought that string manipulation was a pretty expensive task. At some point the kernel will have to strip off the prepended log level metadata. Since they're always the same length, then I guess it's as simple as advancing the char array base pointer a few spots, which isn't expensive. Thanks

Comment: @elBradford: oh right, the log level bytes aren't actually logged, since the log-level filtering happens in kernel.  I was mixed up on that.  The log-level wouldn't need to be pre-pended.  You're right that leaving out the first 2 bytes when memcpying into the output log buffer is trivially cheap.  I think the prefix instead of a separate arg maybe evolved as a backwards-compat way to add log-levels.  So existing code with format strings that didn't include a level prefix kept working, and the change to having log levels could happen gradually.  Code-size in the callers is another advantage.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `printk()` function only takes one `const char*` argument. The `KERN_INFO` macro expands to `"\001" "6"`, yielding:

```
printk("\001" "6" "Log message.\n");
```

The C lexer concatenates adjacent string literal tokens which means that
the above is converted into:

```
printk("\0016Log message.\n");
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that the log levels in the header were numbers and missed that they were string literals. I also had to do a little refresher about how C concatenates string literals separated by a space.

Comment: @PSkocik, but why is macro `KERN_INFO` `"\001" "6"`? I only understand null character at the beginning, but then it is 01 in octal? (as preceding `0`? - so it is `016` in octal after concatenation? In ascii is 016 (`14` in decimal, `0E` in hex, `SO - shift out`, so it is to be sure the next `6` wont be `^`?) and then - I have tried to look up the macro in `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h`, but have not found it. Is it in that dir or somewhere else?

Comment: @Herdsman The syntax for escape sequences is in http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4. Namely for octals it's '\' + 1–3 octal digits (including the initiating 0). So "\0016" (or the equivalent "\001" "6") is parsed as  "{001}6", i.e., byte 1 followed by the digit six (byte 36 in decimal ASCII). The limit of 3 octal digit is why, I guess, an octal escape is used as opposed to a hexadecimal one. The hexadecimal escape doesn't have a digit limit so `"\x111111111aaaabbbcccdddeeefffgreetings, world"` would be interpret everything up to the g as an escape.

Answer (score 7):

The log level isn't an integer but a string literal. String literals next to each other are concatenated into a single string literal at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Because if you search the header files you will see that e.g. [`KERN_INFO`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h#L13) is a macro expanded as a *string literal* (actually multiple string literals, see e.g. the linked cross-reference), and two string literals next to each-other like that will be concatenated into a single string literal by the compiler.

So the call

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Log message.\n");
```

isn't a function call with multiple arguments, it's a function call with a single string literal argument.