# What exactly expands the KERN_INFO, and where it is implemented?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

In this question: [Why doesn't the function printk() use a comma to separate parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492059/why-doesnt-the-function-printk-use-a-comma-to-separate-parameters), someone said `KERN_INFO` expands to `""\001" "6"`. I know the first `\0` is null character, but then what `01` is? As I suppose to be one in octal. When preprocessor concatenate it together to `"\0016"`, the rest after null is `016`, which is `14` in decimal. So I have look up in `ascii` and found it as `0E SO (shift out)`? That doesn't make sense to me and it should have something to do with logging (as it is purpose of `printk`). So what is the meaning of the `KERN_INFO` macro sequences after expansion?

Also, I have tried to look in source, in `/usr/include/linux/kernel.h`, but didn't find there the macro. So is it in `kernel.h` or somewhere else?

Comment: See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h#L14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"\001" "6"` is two string literals that will be concatenated (with any other adjacent string literals) into a single string literal. (The concatenation is done at *translation phase 6* as defined in the C standard.)

The first of those string literals, `"\001"` contains a single *octal escape sequence*, defining a single character. An octal escape sequence in a string literal or a character constant consists of the backslash (`\`) followed by from 1 to 3 octal digits (`001` in this case). In this case, the single character has numeric code 1, which corresponds to the ASCII SOH (start of heading) character.

The string literal `"\0016"` contains sequences for two characters `'\001'` and `'6'`, because an octal escape sequence is always terminated after at most 3 octal digits.

Escape sequences do not cross the boundary between adjacent string literals. (Escape sequences are expanded at translation phase 3, so are already expanded before adjacent string literals are concatenated at translation phase 6). Therefore, the pair of string literals `"\1" "6"` is equivalent (after concatenation) to the single string literal `"\0016"`, not `"\16"`.

As mentioned by [@Peter L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012815/peter-l), the `KERN_INFO` macro and other "kernel level" macros are defined in "include/linux/kern_levels.h" in the Linux kernel source. Actually, that is true since kernel version 3.6. Before kernel version 3.6, they were defined in "include/linux/printk.h" and used a different string format with the kernel level number specified between angle brackets (for example `KERN_INFO` used to be defined as `"<6>"`).

The purpose of these kernel level macros is to prefix the format string parameter of the `printk` function with special codes to designate the log-level to use for the message written to the kernel log (apart from `KERN_CONT` which specifies that the message is to be appended to the previous message).